# Why does `HyperlinkedRelatedField` in Django rest framework needs its view to return `request` paramater as context?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to DRF. While defining a `HyperlinkedRelatedField` in serializer class like this:

```
    class JournalistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       articles = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name="article- 
       detail")
```

im getting the following error:

```
     `HyperlinkedRelatedField` requires the request in the serializer 
      context. Add `context={'request': request}` when instantiating the 
      serializer.
```

when i add `context={'request': request}` in the related APIView class:

```
    class JournalistListCreateAPIView(APIView):

    def get(self,request):
        journalist = Journalist.objects.all()
        serializer = JournalistSerializer(journalist,many=True,context= 
        {'request':request})
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

the HyperLink in the APIView works fine. But i dont understand why request has to be sent while instantiating the serializer. Please help me understand.

Comment: it is unclear what do you mean, write an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does require `request` in context as it builds absolute URL

to be more concrete it is used [`get_url`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/relations.py#L324) serializer method

```
def get_url(self, obj, view_name, request, format):
    ...
    return self.reverse(view_name, kwargs=kwargs, request=request, format=format)
```